# Resolution of an optimal control problem on Julia, by minimizing an integral functional, Ipopt solver does'nt want to solve for certain values of N

Tags: controls, integration, numerical-methods, ipopt, optimal

I am coding the resolution of my optimal control problem on Julia.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/audjy.png)

u and v are my two controls and x=[s,i,m]

I implemented this problem on Julia, and want to solve it with IPOPT.
I approached this integral by using the Trapezoidal rule, like so :
@expression(sys, J1, 0.5 * Δt * sum((A * x[t] + B * u[t] + C * v[t] + A * i[t+1] + B * u[t+1] + C * v[t+1]) for t in 1:N)) .
N being the size of my discretisation.

I defined my constraints and dynamics, then used the Cranck-Nickolson scheme.

My problem is that the solution behaves weirdly; for N \in [200, 7000] my objective is ascendant, i obtain : J1=26 for N=200 and J1=300 for N=7000. Starting from around N=7200, my objective is close to 13, by N=10000, J1=11.

It seems really weird to me to have this change of behaviour, with u that had a singular arc for N \in [200, 7000] and that is now (N=10000) bang bang.

I suspect i have a problem in my code that gives me these weirdlooking results but i dont know where.

I tried using the Runge-kutta method by replacing u and v by their optimal values (found by the solver ) in my dynamics and trying to solve the system to see if s, i and m given by Runge-Kutta coincide with the values initially given by the solver, but i can say that my results do not show that x_solver = x_runge-kutta.

One of the possibilities would be that my approximation of the integral is incorrect,but i'm not sure.

I thank you all for your help !

Comment: It is hard to comment without having some idea of what your x(t) is like and how it is affected by your two controls. Bang-bang can be somewhat unforgiving and trying it with proportional controls might at least help you iron out any bugs in the code.  The other thing to try is a series of N/2, N, 2N to see if there is any pattern to its instability. I presume i[t+1] is a typo for x[t+1]. A better integration routine might help (or hinder).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your time, Here's the problem :
minimize J1(u,v) = int^T_0 (Ai(t) + Bu(t) + Cv(t) ) dt 
(A, B and C are contstatnts). such that
\.s(t) = b -(b -a_1i(t) -a_2m(t))s(t) -cs(t)i(t) -\eta s(t)u(t)
\.i(t) = -(b -a_1i(t) -a_2m(t) + a_1 + g_1 )i(t) +cs(t)i(t) -i(t)v(t)
\.m(t) = -(b -a_1i(t) -a_2m(t) + a_2 + g_2)m(t) + i(t)v(t)
(u(t),v(t)) \in [0,u_{max}]\times [0,v_{max}]; 
(s(0), i(0), m(0)) = (s_0, i_0, m_0);
i(T) \leq D

here, \.f(t) is the derivatives of f in respect to t. b, a_1, a_2g_1, g_2, \eta , D are constants

Comment: Be worth refining your question with these details - its too hard to read it in a comment. One other suggestion is to mock it up in some other application with a solver routine like Excel (its solver is no great shakes) but it might give you a better idea of why the IPOPT code is struggling to try it in a different environment.